# In ZF2, How we can add conditional form fields on some specific selection in select box or after clicking on check box

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

How we can add conditional form fields on some specific selection in select box or after clicking on check box in ZF2 and validate server side code using zf2 feature for validation?

Comment: Use jQuery & hide or show based on selection.

Comment: In ZF2 it is not acceptable.

Comment: How you will put validation in server side for new field which is not registered in form controller?

Comment: Why is jQuery not acceptable to hide & show specific fields upon selection in ZF2? The fields would all be defined in your form, so server side validation wouldn't be an issue. You'd just use javascript to manipulate what is shown to the user.

Comment: But I have condition and there is 50+ fields, how we can register earlier all these fields? It will be manual, it there is any way to make validation for the non registered fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add dynamic field in ZF2 with its validation lib.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, You don't want conditional fields, you want contextual Validators.

For it to validate correctly when it the data is posted to the back end, all 'conditional' fields would need to be added to the form (not required of course), and their validators would implement the context argument of isValid().

```
public function isValid($value, array $context = null) {}
```

That $context variable receives the form data that you can validate against.

Things like

```
if(isset($context['KEYNAME1'])) {
    //validate $value
}
return true;
```

Comment: Thank you, You have right understanding of my problem. I will try your solution.